# Error undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘_expo.Constants.statusBarHeight’)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I'm getting an error for using `paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight`

I used import { Consants } from "expo";

I copied this code from my previous project that i made during university but now this doesnt seem to work

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#3498db",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
```

Comment: The -1 was not me.

Is 
import { Constants } from ‘expo';

Comment: Yes it is, I really don't know why it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Try:
Constants now its a separated package, so run : expo install expo-constants, then import Constants from 'expo-constants’

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/

Comment: thx worked but now i get diff error `createStackNavigator()` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`, is this also due to new sdk version

Comment: Try 
expo start -c
or cleaning the cache:
npm start -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use these marks { and }

just call like this:

```
    import Constants from "expo-constants";
```

Comment: This is the answer. I think you used to need the curly braces until version 39, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following first

```
sh
yarn install expo-constants
```

then the following

```
import Constants to your App.js
import Constants  from "expo-constants";
```